# db2 sequel statement - how to find unique logins per month

Tags: sql, db2

I need to find the unique logins per account per month.

The table has acctNum, function, and insertTimestamp.

I'm not sure how to get the unique acctNums for a particuluar function per month.

When users login their actions are logged to this table. Users can log in many times a day and have different activities inserted into the table as different functions.

I'm only interested in functions = 1(login) for this year.  Any ideas on how to get the sql statement to produce this output?

Comment: count(distinct acctNums)... group by...

Comment: What mean `unique logins per account per month` what make a login unique?

Comment: If one acct# logs in 10 times this month, I need that to count as 1 login for the month.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-query's main purpose is to extract month part from date.

```
select acctNum, monthname, count(*)
(select acctNum, extract(month from insertTimestamp) as monthname
 from tablename
 where functions = 1 
   and extract(year from timestamp) = 2015
 ) dt
group by acctNum, monthname
```

**Note**: `EXTRACT` is ANSI SQL. I don't know if DB2 supports it.